# How to sum all titles even others are empty

Tags: mysql, sql

my query objective is to sum all the fields from (3) tables but i have some problem in generating the `final_total_sum` output if some of the other titles empty the `final_total_sum` is empty....but if all `titles` are not empty my query generate `final_total_sum(output)`.

I wan to do is even other titles are empty my query can still generate a `final_total_sum(output)`.

http://s38.photobucket.com/user/eloginko/media/output_zpsfcab9d54.png.html

current query:

```
SELECT *,
    ROUND(interview_sum +
          other_sum +
          edu_attain2_sum +
          experience2_sum +
          trainings2_sum +
          eligibility2_sum) AS final_total_sum
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROUND((SELECT SUM(t2.inttotal)
         FROM app_interview2 AS t2 
         WHERE t2.atic = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS interview_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(o2.ototal)
         FROM other_app2 AS o2 
         WHERE o2.oaic = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS other_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(s1.edu_attain2)
         FROM qual_stan2 AS s1 
         WHERE s1.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS edu_attain2_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(s2.experience2)
         FROM qual_stan2 AS s2 
         WHERE s2.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS experience2_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(s3.trainings2)
         FROM qual_stan2 AS s3 
         WHERE s3.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS trainings2_sum,

        ROUND((SELECT SUM(s4.eligibility2)
         FROM qual_stan2 AS s4 
         WHERE s4.oaic2 = t.atic)/7,1)
         AS eligibility2_sum,

        t.atid,
        t.atic,
        t.atname,
        t.region,
        t.town,
        t.uniq_id,
        t.position,
        t.salary_grade,
        t.salary

    FROM app_interview2 AS t
    WHERE uniq_id = '$q'
    GROUP BY t.atname 
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT t.atic)) subq
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
   ROUND( ifnull(interview_sum,0) +
          ifnull(other_sum,0) +
          ifnull(edu_attain2_sum,0) +
          ifnull(experience2_sum,0) +
          ifnull(trainings2_sum,0) +
          ifnull(eligibility2_sum,0)) AS final_total_sum
```

In SQL  `x + NULL` always gives NULL, `ifnull` function converts nulls to 0

Answer (score 0):

use like SUM(ifnull(t2.inttotal,0))

Comment: not working...still my final_total_sum is empty if some titles are empty.